# Maven Error: JAVA_HOME Environment variable is not set

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to install Maven on my Mac by following [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/2348/install-maven-mac-os#install-maven-on-mac). It gave me these instructions:

Setting Environment Variables – JAVA_HOME and Path:

> Open .bash_profile and add the following entries to the end of it:

```
JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home"
PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Then, next step is
Setting Maven Environment Variables – M2_HOME and Path

> Open .bash_profile in your favorite text editor and add below lines to the end of it.

```
export M2_HOME="/Users/pankaj/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3"
PATH="${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

So now my final profile looks like this:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
JAVA_HOME="/library/java/javavirtualmachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/contents/home"
PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export M2_HOME="/users/khaled/desktop/repos/identity-theft-protection-binaries/apache-maven-3.1.1"
PATH="${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

When I run "mvn -version" in my terminal however, I get this output:

```
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 11:22:22-0400)
Maven home: /users/khaled/desktop/repos/identity-theft-protection-binaries/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.8.0_275, vendor: Amazon.com Inc.
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

In the 3rd line it says `JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.`, but in the 7th line, it says `Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`

Did I set it incorrectly in my profile? Can I define `PATH` twice like that and export it twice? Or is that incorrect?

Note: The tutorial I was using assumes I am using bash but I am using zsh.

Comment: What happens if you add export in front of the java_home variable? `export JAVA_HOME="/your/path/to/java"`?

Comment: @moffeltje oh wow that's all it took! I guess the tutorial I was using just left that out, thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! I've added it as an answer, please accept if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not exporting the `JAVA_HOME` variable to your ZSH.

Try adding `export` in front of the `JAVA_HOME` variable like so:

`export JAVA_HOME="/library/java/javavirtualmachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/contents/home"`